# Include nuget prerelease in nuget restore in azure buid pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, nuget-package-restore

How to restore nuget packages including prereleases when using azure build pipelines?

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '<guid>'
```

*ERROR*

```
Package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.0.0-rc2 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.0.0-rc2 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
```

**Solved**

I had to install nuget 5.x first!

**Solution**

I've added the following nuget installation to my build pipeline before restoring any packages:

```
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Install nuget 5.x'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '5.x'
```

Comment: Are you having a specific problem restoring prerelease packages?

Comment: @DanielMann I've attached the error message

Comment: @BendEg, It seems you have resolved this issue with nuget 5.x, would you mind share your solution as answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and find answer more easily, thanks.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT done, the solution is pretty simlpe

Comment: @BendEg, Thanks, It is better to separate your answer back from the question, like [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59201729/why-is-my-azure-devops-pipeline-artifact-locked-by-another-process-after-downloa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restoring only works with nuget 5.x. To install nuget 5.x *before* restoring data,
add this lines to your azure-pipelines.yml

```
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Install nuget 5.x'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '5.x'
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could accept it as the answer.